# How to add controller rendering in placeholder in Sitecore SXA?

Tags: sxa, placeholders

Is there any way to add the `custom controller rendering` in a placeholder in `SXA`?

Whenever I add the `controller rendering` inside the placeholder I keep getting errors for example `Object not set to reference` or something like that? I have the code for this specific controller rendering and it does work on other components but when I try to apply it on this new component inside placeholder it just does not work.

Any tips on why is this happening?

Comment: My guess is that you don't have defensive code in your controller to cope with a null/not set datasource item and its erroring before you are able to add a datasource to the rendering. Can you share some code or more detail around your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the issue of the `placeholder`. The `placeholder` will work the same for all kinds of renderings.

It is important that the `controller` inherit from `StandardController` or from a class which inherit from `StandardController`.

The issues of `Object not set to reference`, may come if object is null and to handle this you need to add null reference check in your code.

Last, if your `controller` is not creating any error, then you have to add a static HTML in your view to check if the error is coming by adding any unexpected HTML code? If yes, then you need to correct this.

Thanks.